# How to parse space separated data in pyspark?

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I have below kind of data which is space separated, I want to parse it by space but I am getting issue when particular element has “Space” in it.

```
2018-02-13 17:21:52.809 “EWQRR.OOM” “ERW WERT11”
```

have used below code:

```
import shlex
rdd= line.map(lambda x: shlex.split(x))
```

but its returning deserialized result like `\x00\x00\x00`.

Answer (score 0):

**By default all the text lines are encoded as *unicode* if you are using `sparkContext`'s `textFile` api as the api document of textFile says**

> > Read a text file from HDFS, a local file system (available on all
> >       nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI, and return it as an
> >       RDD of Strings.
> >       If use_unicode is False, the strings will be kept as `str` (encoding
> >       as `utf-8`), which is faster and smaller than unicode. (Added in
> >       Spark 1.2)

And by default this option is true

```
@ignore_unicode_prefix
def textFile(self, name, minPartitions=None, use_unicode=True):
```

And thats the reason you are getting *unicode characters* like `\x00\x00\x00` in the results.

You should include `use_unicode` option while reading the data file to `rdd` as

```
import shlex
rdd = sc.textFile("path to data file", use_unicode=False).map(lambda x: shlex.split(x))
```

Your results should be

```
['2018-02-13', '17:21:52.809', 'EWQRR.OOM', 'ERW WERT11']
```

*you can even include **utf-8 encoding** in map function* as

```
import shlex
rdd = sc.textFile("path to the file").map(lambda x: shlex.split(x.encode('utf-8')))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Input:  
"1234" "ewer" "IIR RT" "OOO" .  

Getting Output . 
1234, ewer, IIR, RT, OOO . 


Desired Output . 
1234, ewer, IIR RT, OOO .

Comment: @SharadBagal, did you try the first one I suggested `.map(lambda x: shlex.split(x.encode('utf-8')))`. this gives me correct result as `['1234', 'ewer', 'IIR RT', 'OOO']`

Comment: you can accept and upvote then :) that will work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.findall()` and regex [`“.+?”|\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/oKwNzA/1) or you can use `“[^”]*”|\S+` by @ctwheels it performs better.

```
rdd = line.map(lambda x: re.findall(r'“.+?”|\S+', x))
```

Comment: `“[^”]*”|\S+` performs better.

Comment: This syntax is incorrect for `rdd`. You'd need something like: `rdd= line.map(lambda x: re.findall(r'“.+?”|\S+', x))`

Answer (score 0):

Input:
"1234" "ewer" "IIR RT" "OOO"

Getting Output:
1234, ewer, IIR, RT, OOO

Desired Output . 
1234, ewer, IIR RT, OOO

Comment: You should update the question with this information and not answer like this one.